# R CMD Check: List of auxiliary functions

Tags: r

I am currently checking my package. `R CMD check` gives me the following warning:

```
* checking for missing documentation entries ... WARNING Undocumented code objects:
```

followed by a list of functions.

The problem seems to be that I have 3 lists containing functions. These, however, are just small functions that exist only because I tried to modularise my code as far as possible. I would like (and have seen that previously in other packages) to just give the function list + documentation without having to provide a documentation for every single tiny function bit.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Just don’t export these functions from your package, then you don’t need to document them. Exported functions should **all** be documented, no matter how small.

Comment: Thanks, Konrad! I, however, think I do not quite get what you mean. If I redo the package skeleton without sourcing these functions beforehand. However, it cannot find the functions any longer then (obviously). What do you mean by exporting? Currently, I am not exporting at all...

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was that within the function list I had
    `funclist <- list(function1 <- function1(){})`

This lead to function1 being sourced upon sourcing funclist. However, when one writes
    `funclist <- list(function1 = function1(){})`

function1 is not sourced and can be addressed via `funclist$function1()` then.